# Client Server Communication in android with button input

Tags: android, client-server

I am new to android programming and I'm working on this code for client server connectivity. I am trying to send values from a client to a server using buttons. I found snippets of a basic client server connectivity program on the internet. In the program, there are multiple buttons. A button when clicked on the client should transmit a string value to the server. The server is then supposed to receive the string and display it on the screen. But when i execute the program all that is displayed is "connected" on the server screen. Ive redirected buttons f,l,r, and b to buttonPressed() in the xml.

Here is the client program:

```
    package com.example.androidromo;


    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;

    //import com.romotive.demo.R;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Client_Second extends MainActivityClient {

private EditText serverIp;

private Button connectPhones;

private EditText text;

private Button f, l, r, b;

private String serverIpAddress = "";

private boolean connected = false;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.client_second);

      serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.server_ip);
    connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect_phones);

     /*connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
      f= (Button) findViewById(R.id.f);
      f.setOnClickListener(buttonPressed(view));
    */

}

     /*
     private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!connected) {
            serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
            if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                cThread.start();

            }
        }
    }
};*/

public void buttonPressed(View view)
{
    // Switch on the view's ID:
    String msg=null;
    switch (view.getId())
    {

    case R.id.f:
        msg="f";
        sendMessage(msg);
        break;


    case R.id.l:
        msg="l";
        sendMessage(msg);
        break;


    case R.id.r:
    msg="r";
    sendMessage(msg);
        break;


    case R.id.b:
        msg="b";
        sendMessage(msg);
        break;

}

}

public void sendMessage(String str)
{
final String str1=str;  

if (!connected) {
    serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
    if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {            


    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
            Log.d("Client_Second", "C: Connecting...");
  //          clientStatus.setText("Connecting...");
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Server_Second.SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) {
                try {

                    Log.d("Client_Second", "C: Sending command.");
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                .getOutputStream())), true);
                        // WHERE YOU ISSUE THE COMMANDS
                      // buttonPressed(f); 
                    //out.println("Hey server");
                    out.println(str1);
                        out.flush();

                        Log.d("Client_Second", "C: Sent.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Client_Second", "S: Error", e);
                }
            }
            //socket.close();
            //Log.d("Client_Second", "C: Closed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Client_Second", "C: Error", e);
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}).start();
}
}
}
}
```

The server code is as follows:

```
 package com.example.androidromo;

 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.InetAddress;
 import java.net.NetworkInterface;
 import java.net.ServerSocket;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.net.SocketException;
 import java.util.Enumeration;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Server_Second extends MainActivityServer {

 private TextView serverStatus;

 // DEFAULT IP
 public static String SERVERIP = "10.0.2.15";

 // DESIGNATE A PORT
 public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

 private Handler handler = new Handler();

 private ServerSocket serverSocket;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.server_second);
     addListenerButton();
     serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.server_status);
     SERVERIP = getLocalIpAddress();
  }

private void addListenerButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Context context = this;
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);
    //button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        //@Override
        /*public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Server_Third.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }*/
    //});
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.preceed);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,Client_Second.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     //    Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
     //  fst.start();
    }


   public void receiveMessage()
    {
     new Thread(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
         try {
             if (SERVERIP != null) {
                 handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         serverStatus.setText("Listening on IP: " + SERVERIP);
                     }
                 });
                 serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                 while (true) {
                     // LISTEN FOR INCOMING CLIENTS
                     Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                     handler.post(new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                             serverStatus.setText("Connected.");
                         }
                    });

                     try {
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new             InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        while(true) {
                        String line = null;
                        if ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                            Log.d("ServerActivity", line);
                             System.out.println(line);


                                    // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO THE FRONT END
                                    // THIS IS WHERE YOU CAN BE CREATIVE


                        }
                        else    {
                        break;
                        }
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                serverStatus.setText("Oops. Connection interrupted.            Please reconnect your phones.");
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        serverStatus.setText("Couldn't detect internet connection.");
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serverStatus.setText("Error");
                }
            });
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }


  }).start();
  }

  // GETS THE IP ADDRESS OF YOUR PHONE'S NETWORK
 private String getLocalIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();    en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("Server_Second", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    try {
         // MAKE SURE YOU CLOSE THE SOCKET UPON EXITING
         serverSocket.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time a user presses a key, the code will re-enter sendMessage() which creates a new socket connection and then loops forever sending the key (because "connected" variable never gets set to false and str1 never changes).

You'll need to re-design this to pass data between threads to send new data on the socket only.

You should not use the clickHandler in XML, hook it up in code. Using it in XML can have problems (i.e., with proguard). Just use `findViewById(R.id.f).setOnClickListener(...)`.